# difference between StartNTService and StartSonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube Server for Java. I noticed that there are 2 batch files.
1) StartNTService
2) StartSonar

I would like to know what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3):

`StartSonar.bat` is to start SonarQube in your command prompt ([documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes)).

`StartNTService.bat` is to start SonarQube as a Windows Service (after having installed it as a service with `InstallNTService.bat`, see [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Windows)).

Comment: Thanks for clarification